# Search with Count occurrences of a specific word within specific stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, regex, stored-procedures, count, ssms

How to search two words by below code to find two words (michael|Kuldeep),

```
declare @word varchar(128)
set @word = (michael|Kuldeep)

select 
    name, 
    (len(object_definition(object_id)) -  len(replace(object_definition(object_id), @word, ''))) / len (@word) as qty
from 
    sys.procedures
where 
    object_definition(object_id) like '%' + @word + '%' 
    and type = 'P'
    and name = 'MenuDetailsSelect'
order by 
    name
```

What I am looking for is to find two names using regular expressions

Comment: Please do not post image. post it as text. Also post some sample data with the expected result

Comment: Script the database and then search the scripts using a language which supports regex

Comment: How to search two words by above code to find two words (michael|Kuldeep),

Comment: TSQL doesn't handle regex natively. Can you explain your usecase so that we're able to help you? What do you need exactly?

Comment: I want to search and know the number of appearances of two separate names in specific stored procedures.

Comment: As I suggested above, I wasn't joking, script out your database (Visual Studio will do it for you) and then use powershell or something that supports regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my goal by using the below code

```
declare @word1 varchar(128)
set @word1 = 'Michael'
select name, (len(object_definition(object_id)) -  len(replace(object_definition(object_id), @word1, ''))) / len (@word1) as Michael
from sys.procedures
where object_definition(object_id) like '%'+@word1+'%' and type = 'P'
AND name='MenuDetailsSelect'

declare @word2 varchar(128)
set @word2 = 'Kuldeep'
select name, (len(object_definition(object_id)) -  len(replace(object_definition(object_id), @word2, ''))) / len (@word2) as Raveena
from sys.procedures
where object_definition(object_id) like '%'+@word2+'%' and type = 'P'
AND name='MenuDetailsSelect'
```

trying to make it as in one query.